# I get this crash from google developers dashboard but i cant understand what is causing it

Tags: android

This is the crash i get in google play developer dashboard. Rebootreceiver extends broadcastreceiver class where onReceive() i call another class that extends service where in that class i call a function to start an alarm. Could this crash caused because google alarms are disabled for my app by the user or something similar? Any thoughts?

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:4238)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700 (ActivityThread.java:274)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2113)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:107)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:237)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8167)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:496)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1100)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
  at android.app.ContextImpl.startServiceCommon (ContextImpl.java:1688)
  at android.app.ContextImpl.startService (ContextImpl.java:1633)
  at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService (ContextWrapper.java:683)
  at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService (ContextWrapper.java:683)
  at com.example.myapp.RebootReceiver.onReceive (RebootReceiver.java:31)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:4229)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700 (ActivityThread.java:274)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2113)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:107)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:237)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8167)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:496)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1100)
```

Answer (score 1):

From your stack trace i find out that your receiver is `RebootReceiver` when device starts your app is in background. If your app targeting API is 26 (Android 8) or above and it tries to start a service when it is in background it will crash with `IllegalStateException` so you need to call `startForgroundService` if Android is 8 or above instead of `startService`:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    context.startForegroundService(new Intent(context, ServedService.class));
} else {
    context.startService(new Intent(context, ServedService.class));
}
```

And in `onHandleIntent` of service you need to call `startForeground` otherwise you get `IllegalStateException` again.

If you have set `targetSdkVersion = 28` (Android 9 / Pie) or above to start foreground service you need to declared the usage of the `FOREGROUND_SERVICE` permission:

```
<manifest ...>
     ...
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
     ...
     <application ...>
     ...
</manifest>
```

Comment: Is it possible to check this on emulator? because i do not get any crashes

Comment: @stefanosn yes check it on a emulator that its Android is 8 or above 8

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion...I have this code in the service intent... public class MyCustomRebootService extends Service {



        Override
        public void onCreate() {
            MainActivity.startAlarm(this);
        }

        Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
            return START_NOT_STICKY;
        }

        Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
            return null;
        }
    }
I guess startForeground not needed because i call mainactivity function?

Comment: I tested it on emulator but does not seem to crash with startService and android 10...any thoughts? both startService and startForegroundservice seem to work on emulator when the app is in background. could it be this line?   if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) i check if boot is completed in RebootReceiver

Comment: The app by the way is closed on boot not even in background...

Comment: any thoughts? does not make any difference in emulator...